# Docker-compose up exited with code 1 but successful docker-compose build

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

When trying to docker-compose up I get errors from the frontend and backend where they exit with code 1. docker ps shows that the postgres container is still running but the frontend and backend still exit. Using npm start, there is no errors. I don't know if it this helps, but my files do not copy from my src folder to /usr/src/app/ so maybe there is an error with my docker-compose or Dockerfiles.

Docker ps shows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES 
509208b2243b        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 hours ago        Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   example_db_1
```

```
docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./frontend/build:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/usr/src/app/src
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: example
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example1234
      POSTGRES_DB: example
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    # Automatic certificate renewal
    # entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

This is what the backend Dockerfile looks like.

```
FROM node:current-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NODE_ENV=production

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And the output error:

```
example_db_1 is up-to-date
Starting example_certbot_1 ... done
Starting example_backend_1 ... done
Starting example_frontend_1 ... done
Attaching to example_db_1, example_certbot_1, example_backend_1, example_frontend_1
backend_1   |
backend_1   | > example-backend@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
backend_1   | > npx tsc; node ./out/
backend_1   |
certbot_1   | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot_1   | Certbot doesn't know how to automatically configure the web server on this system. However, it can still get a certificate for you. Please run "certbot certonly" to do so. You'll need to manually configure your web server to use the resulting certificate.
frontend_1  | 2020/02/13 11:35:59 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:21
frontend_1  | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:21
db_1        | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1        | This user must also own the server process.
db_1        |
db_1        | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1        | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1        | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1        |
db_1        | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1        |
db_1        | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1        | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1        | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1        | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1        | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1        | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
db_1        | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1        | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1        | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1        | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1        |
db_1        | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1        | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1        | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1        |
db_1        | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1        |
db_1        |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1        |
db_1        | waiting for server to start....2020-02-12 21:51:40.137 UTC [43] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.147 UTC [43] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.229 UTC [44] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-12 21:51:39 UTC
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.240 UTC [43] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1        |  done
db_1        | server started
db_1        | CREATE DATABASE
db_1        |
db_1        |
db_1        | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1        |
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.606 UTC [43] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1        | waiting for server to shut down....2020-02-12 21:51:40.608 UTC [43] LOG:  aborting any 
active transactions
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.614 UTC [43] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 50) exited with exit code 1
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.614 UTC [45] LOG:  shutting down
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.652 UTC [43] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1        |  done
db_1        | server stopped
db_1        |
db_1        | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1        |
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.728 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.729 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432   
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.729 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432        
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.748 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.788 UTC [61] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-12 21:51:40 UTC
db_1        | 2020-02-12 21:51:40.799 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1        | 2020-02-13 09:51:41.562 UTC [787] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:09:27.384 UTC [865] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:09:27.384 UTC [865] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
db_1        |   Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:32:18.771 UTC [1] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:32:18.806 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" 
(PID 67) exited with exit code 1
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:32:18.806 UTC [62] LOG:  shutting down
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:32:18.876 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1        |
db_1        | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization   
db_1        |
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:33:01.343 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:33:01.343 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432   
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:33:01.343 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432        
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:33:01.355 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:33:01.427 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-13 11:32:18 UTC
db_1        | 2020-02-13 11:33:01.466 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections   
example_certbot_1 exited with code 1
example_frontend_1 exited with code 1
backend_1   | Authenticating with database...
backend_1   | internal/fs/utils.js:220
backend_1   |     throw err;
backend_1   |     ^
backend_1   |
backend_1   | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem'
backend_1   |     at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
backend_1   |     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
backend_1   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/out/index.js:68:23)
backend_1   |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
backend_1   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
backend_1   |   syscall: 'open',                                 811:32)
backend_1   |   code: 'ENOENT',                                  loader.js:723:14)
backend_1   |   path: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/s/loader.js:1043:10)privkey.pem'
backend_1   | }
backend_1   | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
backend_1   | npm ERR! errno 1
backend_1   | npm ERR! example-backend@1.0.0 start: `npx tsc; noprivkey.pem'de ./out/`
backend_1   | npm ERR! Exit status 1
backend_1   | npm ERR!
backend_1   | npm ERR! Failed at the example-backend@1.0.0 startde ./out/` script.
backend_1   | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                   script.
backend_1   |                                                    here is likely additional logging ou
backend_1   | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
backend_1   | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-13T11_36_10_3:30Z-debug.log                                                    30Z-debug.log
example_backend_1 exited with code 1
```

There are no errors with certbot when run outside this project.

Directory structure:

```
src/
    - docker-compose.yml
    - init.letsencrypt.sh
    - .gitignore
    backend
        src
        - Dockerfile
        - package.json
        - .gitignore
    data
        nginx
        - app.conf
    frontend
        src
        - Dockerfile
        - package.json
        - .gitignore
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Updated nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /frontend {
        proxy_pass http://example.org:8080;
        try_files $uri /public/index.html;
    }

    location /backend {
        proxy_pass http://example.org:3000;
    }

    location /db {
        proxy_pass http://example.org:5432;
    }
}
```

new error when changing .gitignore:

```
frontend_1  | 2020/02/13 16:34:58 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem": 
BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
frontend_1  | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
example_frontend_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Do you have `options-ssl-nginx.conf` inside `data/certbot/conf`?

Comment: Yeah it exists.

Comment: Are sure? It is not in your directory structure.

Comment: Sorry, it exists on my server. I assume when I ran certbot it created the directory structure. It exists at /src/data/certbot - same with ssl-dhparams.

Comment: I just looked at my .gitignore file and it was ignoring that directory. However, now I have another error which is shown in the original post.

Comment: Hm. It is hard to say where the error is. Maybe is a other architecture better for you : Configure your docker with only non-tls ports (only normal 80/8080 http). Install the certbot on your host-machine and set up a reverse proxy for your services (which terminates the tls-encryption). My experiences with this setup are really good - easy to configure and not such a mess with your docker-compose-volumes. I will write a detailed answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll give that a go and get back to you.

Comment: Your welcome. I edited my post for you. Have fun with it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help again, seems to have fixed some stuff - the backend and the database run but now the frontend has this error ```frontend_1  | 2020/02/14 14:24:55 [emerg] 1#1: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command 
line
frontend_1  | nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line```

Comment: There is something wrong with your nginx config.

Comment: Fixed the errors now when tailing nginx error log, I get error 13: permission denied in /var/www/html.

Comment: We can not tell you where the problem is. You need to share some informations with us.

Comment: $ sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```2020/02/15 16:24:14 [error] 20440#20440: *1 directory index of "/var/www/html/frontend/" is forbidden, client: 209.95.60.151, server: _, request: "GET /frontend/ HTTP/1.1",``` Sorry, forgot to add that. *updated original post to show new /data/nginx/nginx.conf. I removed the 443 ssl server because I don't need it right now.

Comment: The problem with is the file, that you use the folder `/var/www/html/` which not exists. And I think you misunderstood me: Dont put the reverse proxy into docker - it is for the hostmachine (no docker). And you can not use the reverse proxy for your database (the reverse proxy can only route http-traffic).

Comment: Ah, okay. I see what you're saying. I should've also mentioned that some of my previous errors were fixed by changing my host directory to /var/www/html where my root files are placed. I'll put the reverse proxy into the nginx config on my server. Thank you for your help once again!

Comment: If my answer was your solution, then mark it as solved. Or write a own answer and describe how you solved your problem. ^^

Comment: Sorry forgot to reply, the issue was with my nginx and docker-compose config. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setup seems very complicated. My advice for you: Try to reduce the complicated overhead with the certbot as own docker-container.

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      # no source-code of the frontend via volumes - 
      # only a nginx-image with your source. 
      # nginx-conf as volume is valid.
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    # dont put your source as volume in, 
    # your docker-image should contains the whole code
    # and no certbot magic here
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: example
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example1234
      POSTGRES_DB: example
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

This is much cleaner and easy to read. Now you should setup a reverse proxy on your hostmachine ([easy with nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)). Configure your published ports into your nginx-reverse-proxy (`proxy_pass localhost:8080` for your frontend as example).

After that you can install the certbot and obtain your lets-encrypt-certificates. The certbot should discover your nginx-endpoints automatically and can automatic renew your certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I still get the same errors regardless of adding what you suggested. Does it make a difference if the certificates already exist before running docker-compose up?

Comment: No. Can you post your app.conf for us? It seems that there is the error (it tries to do something with `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf` which is not there).